# How do you draw a freehand polygon in ios simulator using openlayers?

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-simulator, openlayers, openstreetmap

In my app in a browser i can do this with the shift key.  But does anyone know how to do this using the ios simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the appropriate option to the `DrawFeature` control handler (`freehand`):

```
new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectorLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Path, {
    handlerOptions: {
        freehand: true
    }
});
```

Then you’ll always be in freehand mode, without the need for the shift key.

Comment: sorry im somewhat new to stackoverflow